# Read several numpy array from csv in one line

Tags: python, csv, numpy

I have csv file with some data. I am trying to read numpy arrays from csv file, so here is code of the program:

```
import numpy as np
train = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1], 'r'))
X = []
y = []
for row in train:
    X.append(row[1:])
    y.append(row[0])
X = np.array(X)
y = np.array(y)
```

I know that Python syntax is very unusual. So is there any way to write turn loop in something like that?

```
import numpy as np
train = csv.reader(open(sys.argv[1], 'r'))
X, y = [... for row in train]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you are not reading the whole csv file using [`np.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt)?

```
>>> from io import StringIO
>>> txt = '''
... 1, 2, 3
... 4, 5, 6
... 7, 8, 9'''
>>> 
>>> xs = np.loadtxt(StringIO(txt), delimiter=',')
>>> xs
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.]])
>>> 
>>> x, y = xs[:, 1:], xs[:, 0]
>>> x
array([[ 2.,  3.],
       [ 5.,  6.],
       [ 8.,  9.]])
>>> y
array([ 1.,  4.,  7.])
```